# Did the most recent kernel update break /etc/security/limits.conf?

Tags: kernel

We've been having some trouble with a server that's had automatic updates enabled on it. This past Monday, it seems that a new kernel was installed, and after rebooting our MySQL server started behaving like its file limit had been exceeded. I check the mysql user's `ulimit -n` output, and sure enough it's set to 1024.

I try to change this in /etc/security/limits.conf like so:

```
mysql           soft    nofile  20000
mysql           hard    nofile  25000
```

then when I try to check the user's ulimit again, it's still set to 1024. Rebooting hasn't had any effect either. It's like this file isn't being read at all.

Also, setting the ulimit manually does work.

Kernel version is 3.13.0-37-generic

Comment: By using the same procedure as I used to test it in the first place. Su to the user, enter `ulimit -n` on the command line.

Comment: Are you kidding me? `su mysql -s /bin/bash`

Comment: Not kidding, just someone who uses `sudo` more than `su`. That said, that particular test is unreliable. On a Debian squeeze machine, `www-data` with limit set to 16384 still shows 1024 for the limit when checked using `su www-data -s /bin/bash`.

Comment: well that explains why the test has been failing, now all I need to do is discover why MySQL is getting Error 24's for having too many files open, when the limit is set to 25000 files.

Comment: Could you try testing `ulimit -n` after starting a shell via `sudo -u www-data /bin/bash -l`?

Comment: If you mean "mysql" where you say "www-data", then yes, I still see the ulimit set to 1024 when I use that test. Also, I've tried setting the `ulimit -n 25000` within the mysql init script, without success.

Comment: Also, there are only 4555 files in the /var/lib/mysql tree, so we're not exceeding that 25000 file limit.

Comment: Even more importantly, this behaviour in MySQL only started when the kernel was updated. It was working fine on Friday.

Comment: Ah, yes, I meant `mysql`. Is `pam_limits.so` uncommented in the files in `/etc/pam.d`? What does `grep pam_limits.so /etc/pam.d -R` say? Also, since you say this happened after a kernel upgrade, please add the version of of Ubuntu and the kernel as well: `lsb_release -cd`, `uname -r`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18060/discussion-between-ernie-and-muru).

Answer (score 1):

It turned out this was an error in the MySQL configuration. The variable `open_files_limit` was in the wrong section of /etc/mysql/my.cnf, and wouldn't load.